# Tenho um menu com 3 ícones: o 1º a esquerda e o 3º a direita. Preciso que o 2º fique no centro

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um site responsivo, começando pelo menu, mas estou com o seguinte problema:

[image]

Então, preciso que o ícone que está do lado do 1º, fique ao meio, de uma forma que fique centralizado também para a versão Mobile.

Código:

```css
   /* =============== RESET =============== */

* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

i {
  color: white;
}


/* =============== HEADER =============== */

button i:hover {
  color: #D8D8D8;
}

.cabecalho {
  padding: 3% 4%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.menu {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.loja {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.pesquisar {
  background: black;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Alpha Tech - Eletrônica e Informática</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data/logos/favicon.png">

  <meta name="keywords" content="alpha tech, loja, informatica, eletronica, conserto, reparo, tecnico">

  <meta name="description" content="Faça seu orçamento! Consertamos Celulares, Tablet's, Notebook's, Monitores e muito mais! Vendemos também vários produtos relacionados a Eletrônica e Informática, entre em nossa loja virtual!">
  <meta name="author" content="Vander Pires de Oliveira">
  <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright © Alpha Tech">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonimous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <header class="cabecalho">
    <button class="menu">
    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
   </button>

    <button class="loja">
    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-store fa-lg"></i></a>
   </button>

    <button class="pesquisar">
    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
   </button>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas diferentes de fazer isso, mas a mais prática é colocar `display:flex` no *content box* no qual os ícones estão dentro e usar a propriedade `justify-content: space-between;` para distribuir igualmente os ícones dentro do *container*. Como vc só tem 3 ícones vai ficar um a esquerda, um no centro e o outro a direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código referente a imagem acima.

**OBS 1:** Usando `display:flex` no pai vc não precisa mais de `float` nos filhos.

**OBS 2:** A altura da barra fica variando pq vc colocou seu `padding` em `%`, se for em `PX` vc não vai ter esse "problema"

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

i {
  color: white;
}


/* =============== HEADER =============== */

button i:hover {
  color: #D8D8D8;
}

.cabecalho {
  padding: 3% 4%;
  width: 100%;

  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /* propriedades para fazer o alinhamento  */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;

  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.loja {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.pesquisar {
  background: black;
  
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonimous">


<header class="cabecalho">
  <button class="menu">
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
    </button>

  <button class="loja">
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-store fa-lg"></i></a>
    </button>

  <button class="pesquisar">
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
    </button>
</header>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou aqui do jeito que queria...

Comment: @zAllan sem problemas meu caro!